# Reload specific files in an external stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm loading CSVs to from S3 to a table in snowflake using COPY INTO. The table is truncated each time the process runs (data is persisted in a subsequent staging table). In the event of the COPY INTO finishing but the job failing before loading to the persistent staging table, the records are lost on the next load and the COPY INTO command will ignore the loaded files.

Our archive process applies to files >1 day old so I can't switch to a force load temporarily as irrelevant files would be loaded.

Manually reducing to just the missing files isn't ideal as we have 100+ tables which are partitioned by table name in S3.

Can anyone suggest any other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider changing your process to copy the files to both the staging location, as well as your archive location at the same time, and then leverage the PURGE command in your COPY INTO.  This way errored files stick around for the next run, and you still have a full archive available.